# How to check if array of class?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a class named Form.

```
export class Form {}
```

How can I check if a variable is an array of `Form`?

```
const foo: Form = new Form()

if (foo instanceof Form) {}

const baz: Form[] = [new Form(), new Form()]

?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said `I am not worrying about different types`  Ok just check the to see `baz` is array or not `Array.isArray(value)` and then check the only first item by instance of like this:

```
if (Array.isArray(baz) && baz.length > 0 && baz[0] instanceof Form) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check if every single entry in your `baz` array is indeed an instance of `Form`:

```
const baz = [new Form(), new Form()];
console.log(baz.every(entry => entry instanceof Form));  // true

const baz2 = [new Form(), new Form(), ''];
console.log(baz2.every(entry => entry instanceof Form));  // false
```

[See proof-of-concept on TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD2AnAttA3gXwFBePAdhAC7QBGYAXtALzQDa%20ApgO5xLIAUAlADTROsEKbgF0A3LgIR4IRgDoQ8AOYdyFOYwBujRAE8OjfET00AfNEPHd0AJaEiYfMEbwAZmxRcuY6NAD0ftDGAK6MOHj2ZJQATDT0Ah6cvPwsidx8AOQZ4pKEMvKKKmrRGtp6BkYm1OaWJnbEjs5uiV4%20-oGuYCAQYUA).

Comment: I am not worrying about different types in the array. So, I am asking, is there any condition syntax like `baz instanceof Form[]`?

Comment: @berkan That is exactly what my answer does. To check if an array is `Form[]`, that means you need to check if every single element in the array is an instanceof `Form`

Comment: @berkan No there isn't same syntax like this `baz instanceof Form[]`. You need to create a loop and check for each item of array